# MS Project library

Tags: c#, ms-project

Does anybody know of a good library for reading/modifying ms project files?

Answer (score 2):

For me the COM interface also worked like a charm. There are a few traps, take care of the CultureInfo of your thread, set it to "en-US", there seems to be a similar issue as the LCID bug in Excel. Also call the methods of the COM from one single thread.

I had a look at your profile and could not judge if you know how to deal with COM under .NET or not. In our project just add a reference to the COM and then you should be able to use the methods. The MsProject API is quite low level (Database oriented) but proved to be quite reliable (that was not the case when I used Excel COM API).

I would go this way because then you do not depend on a 3rdparty library (only on MS) and you can do everything you could also do from within Macros. Other solutions might restrain you to what was implemented by the SDKs...

Answer (score 1):

Does Aspose Tasks not do what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an example in the ILOG Gantt SDK that will load MS project files; I can't remember if it saves too, but it might help as a starter.

Answer (score 0):

What about MS Project COM interface?  I used it to make some web reports with it in the past...

Answer (score 0):

The COM interface is a good bet as others have said. Microsoft have some more stuff [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/project_programmability/).

That said it might be easier to use [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/index.html) which purports to provide a robust and open API for manipulating various types of MS Project file.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use COM interface and you need to use a namespace"Microsoft.Office.Introp.MSProject"